# \Citet stops working when \bibpunct with numeric style is used

Tags: natbib, capitalization

Consider this MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{vonSurname2020,
  year = {2020},
  author = {von Surname, Auhtor},
  title = {Real Interesting},
  journal = {International Journal of Honest Peer-reviewing}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
% \bibpunct[, ]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,} % <---- good
\bibpunct[, ]{[}{]}{;}{n}{,}{,} % <---- bad
\begin{document}

\citet{vonSurname2020}

\Citet{vonSurname2020}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\end{document}
```

With the `good` `\bibpunct` line activated I get:

[image]

but if I uncomment `bad` `\bibpunct` then:

[image]

Why is that?  This seems to happen regardless of which `\bibliographystyle` I use.

How can I have the “von” prefix properly capitalized with numeric style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but I didn't test if it works with longer author lists:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\NAT@citexnum{\let\NAT@nm\NAT@name}{\def\NAT@nm{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@name}}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```